# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ ....z

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Why i am getting this error?

"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

---

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

---

```
public interface API {
@GET("getmenu.php")
Observable<List <MainMenu>> getMenu();
}
```

MainMenu.class :

```
public class MainMenu {
    public String ID;
    public String Name;
    public String Link;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because what comes in json is not compliant with `List <MainMenu>` model. If you want to have specific answer, post your json and the `MainMenu` model.

Comment: Read back the question
Modified

Comment: @MahmoudEssam your update addresses model question however you did not address json part. Raw json (ideally - as captured by Wireshark) is needed. Your model expects top level list but you are getting plain string on top, that's the issue.

Comment: Explain more ... !